# Regex Match the last word of the line

Tags: c#, .net, regex, match

I have this HTML

```
<br />
<strong>Name:</strong> Josef
<br />
```

And I want to match the name, "Josef" in this case.
I have some problems as Josef is the last word of that string if you don't use m with regex.
My approach

```
^<strong>Name:</strong> (.*?)$
```

doesn't seem to work, how is this done correctly?

Comment: Are all three lines of your HTML in a single `string` variable? Are there literal line breaks before/after the `<br />` tags?

Comment: can you show us more of your `html`..`regex` is not recommended for parsing `html`..with your `expanded html` we can suggest you some other workaround..that html is not sufficient..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your HTML string has two literal linebreaks in it like as it seems to, you'll need to set your regex to [multiline mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx#Multiline) so that `$` matches `end-of-line` as well as `end-of-string`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `html parser` instead of `regex`

---

But if you still need it

You can do

```
<strong>Name:</strong>\s*(\w+)
```

Comment: Singleline doesn't change anything here. It only affects the behavior of `.`.

Comment: Agreed if I'd do multiple operations but it is only this one operation and I don't want to load up HTMLAgilityPack cause of this.

Comment: @m.buettner, @Some1 [muitiline mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx#Multiline) makes e.g. `$` match before a line break as well as just the end of a string, so _that_ might be what's needed here. It _doesn't_ only affect the handling of `.`

Comment: @Rawling yup. no one disagrees with that. I said singleline, you said multiline. Singleline affects (only) `.`. Multiline affects (only) `^` and `$`.

Comment: @m.buettner Sorry, you're right. I assumed "single line" and "multiline" were opposite sides of the same coin, but now I see there's a gap between them.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Matthias Waldkircher,

Two solutions:

1) Using your expression:

```
"(?:^|\n)<strong>Name:</strong> (.*?)(?:$|\r)"
```

2) With other expression:

```
"</strong>\s(.*?)(?:\r|$)"
```

In both solutions your desired match will be a in this prop of the match object match.Groups[1].Value.

MetaChars used:

```
(?:) // unamed/unumered group;
\n // new line;
\r // carriage return;
^ // beginning of the input;
| // or
() // numered group,
$ // end of the input.
```

I wish you the best,

Sincerely,

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex pattern which finds a position following a prefix:

```
(?<=prefix)find
```

In your case

```
(?<=^<strong>Name:</strong> ).*$
```

It will find exactly "Josef" and you will not need to use groups. But consider using the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for searches withing html.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want *Joseph* why not use the RightToLeft regex option to give the parser a hint to start and the end and works towards the beginning. The pattern is still left to right, and it translates to this:

```
string data =@"
<br />
<strong>Name:</strong> Josef
<br />
";

string pattern = @"\</strong\>\s+([^\r\n]+)";

// Put in | | to show no whitespace leakage.
Console.WriteLine ("|{0}|", Regex.Match(data, pattern, RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Groups[1].Value);

// Outputs
// |Josef|
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiline mode to make the anchors work right, I would ditch the anchors:

```
<strong>Name:</strong>\s*([^\r\n<]+)
```

HTML is not a line-based format, so it doesn't really make sense to use line anchors in it.  That piece of text may be on its own line today, but tomorrow it could get edited and the newlines removed; it would still be valid HTML and it would still be rendered exactly the same.

Another potential problem is that the newlines could be `\r\n` (carriage-return + linefeed) instead of just `\n`.  The .NET regex flavor doesn't recognize `\r` as (part of) a line separator, so the `$` will match the position between the `\r` and the `\n`, and the `\r` will get captured along with the name ( i.e. `"Josef\r"`).